# Vue passing data back multiple levels

Tags: vue.js

i'm having issues passing a value through multiple components, I think I have got it wrong, can someone help me please:

```js
Vue.component('layout', {
    props: [ 'current' ],
    template: `<deformer :current="current" @current="$emit('update:current', $event)" />`
});

Vue.component('deformer', {
    props: [ 'current' ],
    template: `<button @click="$emit('update:current', current + 1)">Increase {{ current }}</button>`
});

new Vue({
    data: {
        current: 1
    },
    watch: {
        current: function(value) {
            // Do something with value
            console.log(value);
        }
    }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    {{ current }}
    <layout :current="current" />
</div>
```

So that button should increase the number within the main app, but if this is changed from somewhere else this change should also reflect on the button.

Comment: Please explain in detail.

Comment: @RobertRocha updated question.

Comment: you need to catch the event in your parent element and then update current

Answer (score 0):

`current` should be a `prop`, not `data`.  The `emit` message will notify the parent component to change the value, and it will trickle back down through the `prop`.

This design ensures only one component owns the data.

Comment: My mistake, it is a prop. I just coded that example and put it as data by mistake. Just updated my question.